# replace repeating html-tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, quill

I am using the quill.js editor to allow users to write comments. The problem with quill.js is, if they press enter, a new paraph is generated.

```
<p><br></p>
```

This allows them to create infinite new lines. For example the input:

```
fffff ffff fff
fff


fffffff



ff
```

would generate this html:

```
<p>fffff ffff fff</p>
<p>fff</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>fffffff</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>ff</p>
```

But I want to get a result like this:

```
<p>fffff ffff fff</p>
<p>fff</p>
<p><br></p>
<p>fffffff</p>
<p><br></p>
<p>ff</p>
```

so if the newline code is repeated, it should be replaced with a single new line. How do I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you need a better editor... Personally I use [ACE](https://ace.c9.io/) and it just gives me plain text, which I can then format as desired.

Comment: You can avoid sending the comment if it's blank but need to see some code on how the form is sent to give you any solution.

Comment: I should add, the result is given as a string. I was thinking about solving this problem with string.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/g, "<p><br></p>") Something is missing in the first expression to get the repeated new lines aswell. This code would do nothing at all. It just replaces <p><br></p> with <p><br></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if there are two or more occurrences of the `<p><br></p>` followed by a new line and if so, you replace it with a single one like so:

```js
const markup = `
<p>fffff ffff fff</p>
<p>fff</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>fffffff</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>ff</p>
<p><br></p>
`;

const result = markup.replace(/(<p><br><\/p>\n){2,}/g, '<p><br><\/p>\n');

console.log(result);
```

You could even as far as:

```js
const markup = `
<p>fffff ffff fff</p>
<p>fff</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>fffffff</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>ff</p>
<p><br></p>
`;

const target = '<p><br><\/p>\n';

const result = markup.replace(new RegExp(`(${target}){2,}`, 'g'), target);

console.log(result);
```

So you can change the element easily in the future.

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you really have no other options, then you can do something like this:

```js
function cleanupHtml() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/gi, '');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cleanupHtml);
```

```html
<p>fffff ffff fff</p>
<p>fff</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>fffffff</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>ff</p>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have right now, you can see it in my comment under my question. The problem with that is, now I don't allow empty lines at all, but one should be allowed.